# calculator number formatting C#

Tags: c#

I am working on a calculator in C# and this project is going to end me. I just learned about classes and my extent of formatting decimals is basically using formatting codes ex: ("C") for currency.

Here is what the project asks for:

"The results of multipication should show no more decimal places than the result of the first number than in the second number. Example 55.5*89.68 = 4977.240" and then a few other restrictions on addition, subtraction, and so on.

Currently the way my program is coded everything looks fine accept for multiplication. I believe what is throwing of my answers is how I have coded my division method.

Here is the code starting from my operator buttons. I did not format my output until I got to Division because that was the only test data that did not run correctly. When I formatted Division it is now throwing off Multiplication. I am unsure how to make both Multiplication and Division happy.

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Add(displayValue);
        newValue = true;
        decimalEntered = false;
        displayValue = calc.CurrentValue;
        txtDisplay.Text = displayValue.ToString();
    }

    private void btnSubtract_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Subtract(displayValue);
        newValue = true;
        decimalEntered = false;
        displayValue = calc.CurrentValue;
        txtDisplay.Text = displayValue.ToString();
    }

    private void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Multiply(displayValue);
        newValue = true;
        decimalEntered = false;
        displayValue = calc.CurrentValue;
        txtDisplay.Text = displayValue.ToString();
    }

    private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Divide(displayValue);
        newValue = true;
        decimalEntered = false;
        displayValue = calc.CurrentValue;
        displayValue = Math.Round(displayValue, 8);
        txtDisplay.Text = displayValue.ToString();
    }




    private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (newValue)
                calc.Equals();
            else
                calc.Equals(displayValue);
            displayValue = calc.CurrentValue;
            displayValue = Math.Round(displayValue, 8);
            txtDisplay.Text = displayValue.ToString();
            newValue = true;
            decimalEntered = false;
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException)
        {
            displayValue = 0;
            txtDisplay.Text = "Cannot divide by zero.";
            newValue = true;
            decimalEntered = false;
        }
    }

}
```

}

I also should note I tried adding the following code into my division statement instead of the way I have it above, and this gave me errors which is why I went back to the way I have it above.

```
calc.Divide(displayValue);
        newValue = true;
        decimalEntered = false;
        displayValue = calc.CurrentValue;
        txtDisplay.Text = displayValue.ToString("f8");
```

Comment: Didn't you post this an hour ago ? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967495/c-sharp-calculator-class)

Comment: I've flagged this for moderator attention as an intentional duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19967495/62576, posted by the same user, so this one can be closed. **Please don't post duplicate questions here.** If you have information to add or change, do so by editing your other question instead.

Comment: I've merged the two questions, you can simply edit the original as needed. If you need to ask a follow up question, which is _related_ to that one, then just reference it and proceed with the new question. Good luck on your assignment, don't worry - it'll pass :)